# How to exclude the first and last row in a table when using CSS counter-increment

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm numbering the rows in a table with the code below. But I need to exclude the first row which is the head, and the last row with is just the last row. The exclusion on the head works fine. I've tried this:

```
table#thisNet {
    counter-reset: netLogCounter;
}

table#thisNet td:first-child::before {
    counter-increment: netLogCounter;
}

table#thisNet tr:not(thead) tr:not(:last-child)  td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(netLogCounter);
}
```

But that leaves each blank ... no numbers at all.

I've also given this a try:

```
table#thisNet tr:not(thead, last-child::before)  td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(netLogCounter);
}
```

But again no joy.
With only this it works but the last row is numbers.

```
table#thisNet tr:not(thead) td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(netLogCounter);
}
```

Can both the first and last row be excluded from the counter-increment, if so how?

Comment: `table#thisNet tr:not(thead):not(:last-child)  td:first-child::before` ?

Comment: This left the last two rows off.

Comment: Have you tried `:not(first-of-type)` `:not(last-of-type)`

Comment: I'm not sure about the syntax so I first tried it like this. table#thisNet  :not(first-of-type) :not(last-of_type)  {
    content: counter(netLogCounter);
} But that didn't work, so I tried like this; table#thisNet tr:not(thead) :not(first-of-type) :not(last-of_type)  {
    content: counter(netLogCounter);
} Both ways returned no numbers at all. So I tried it one more time like this: table#thisNet tr:not(thead) :not(first-of-type) :not(last-of_type) td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(netLogCounter);
} but again no numbers at all. Obviously its a syntax thing.

Comment: @KeithDKaiser please add that as an edition to the question, it will be easier to read. Also if you provide the HTML to generate a [mcve], it will be easier to replicate and find a solution for the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a counter for the table, and increment it in every row that is not the first (`:first-child`) nor the last (`:last-child`) with a selector like this:

```css
table#thisNet tr:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  counter-increment: netLogCounter;
}
```

Here you can see a demo:

```css
table#thisNet {
  counter-reset: netLogCounter 0;
}

table#thisNet tr:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  counter-increment: netLogCounter;
}

table#thisNet tr:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) td:first-child::before {
  content: counter(netLogCounter); 
}
```

```html
<table id="thisNet">
  <tr><td>ID</td><td>Value</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>TOTAL</td><td>15</td></tr>
</table>
```

Ideally, the table could be structured like this:

```html
<table>
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tbody>...</tbody>
  <tfoot>...</tfoot>
</table>
```

Then you would only want to count the rows inside the `tbody` simplifying the logic of the selector:

```css
table#thisNet tbody tr {
  counter-increment: numRows;
}
```

And do something like this demo:

Here you can see a demo:

```css
table#thisNet {
  counter-reset: netLogCounter 0;
}

table#thisNet tbody tr {
  counter-increment: netLogCounter;
}

table#thisNet tbody tr td:first-child::before {
  content: counter(netLogCounter); 
}
```

```html
<table id="thisNet">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>ID</th><th>Value</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td></td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>6</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr><td>TOTAL</td><td>15</td></tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: It all came together by making the last row <tfoot>.